# Executing raw query in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to execute some raw queries in laravel 5.3. the queries are simple but im getting errors.

```
table name: users
columns: id|name|email|phone|created_at|updated_at
```

my query:

```
SELECT created_at AS member_since, count(*) as row_count
FROM users
GROUP by MONTH(created_at);
```

This raw query works fine when I execute this on phpmyadmin. But when I execute this using laravel's database query builder i get error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 
'query.users.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 
    'query.users.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select created_at AS 
    member_since from `users` group by MONTH(created_at))
```

here is my controller:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('created_at AS member_since', 'count(*) AS row_count'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
            ->get();

return response()->json($users);
```

Please correct me if Im wrong. Are there any better ways to execute raw queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand the error you're getting. This question is all about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/38551525/2474872

Now, with that in mind you have two choices

- Disable `only_full_group_by`setting.
- Follow the indications provided
  by the error message:

  ```
    $users = DB::table('users')
      ->select(DB::raw('created_at AS member_since, count(*) AS row_count'))
      ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), 'created_at')
      ->get();
  ```

`groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), 'created_at')` can also be `groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at), created_at')`